# Datalist com array

Tags: javascript, array

com pouco de conhecimento e busca consegui chegar nesse código onde busco criar uma DATALIST que ao selecionar uma opção do name... Completar os outros dois campos RG e tel no input automaticamente ...

Já tentei então consegui... Alguém poderia me ajudar.

```js
var test = [{
    name: "Rodrigo",
    rg: "00.000",
    tel: "(01) 00000-000"
  },
  {
    name: "Monica",
    rg: "85.000",
    tel: "(02) 00000-000"
  },
  {
    name: "Maria",
    rg: "68.000",
    tel: "(03) 00000-000"
  }
];

var options = '';


for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  options += '<option value="' + test[i].name + '" />';
  document.getElementById('maltList').innerHTML = options;
  document.getElementById('rg').value = test[i].rg;
  document.getElementById('tel').value = test[i].tel;
}
```

```html
<input name="malt" list="maltList" />
<datalist id="maltList"></datalist>
<input name="rg" type="text" id="rg"> //
<input name="tel" type="text" id="tel">
```

Comment: O problema é que você define os valores do RG e telefone dentro do laço em que cria as opções. O ideal seria que você fizesse isso quando o usuário preencher o nome, buscando no seu array. Veja sobre o evento `change` do input e utilize-o para isso.

Comment: *...Já tentei então consegui...* acho que é *...Já tentei e não consegui...*

Comment: Exatamente Augusto, Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um conteúdo excelente que pode te auxiliar em seu aprendizado é a documentação. Na [documentação do HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) existe uma explicação detalhada do objetivo do elemento `input` e seu objetivo.

> O **elemento HTML** `<input>` é usado para criar controles interativos para
> formulários baseados na web para receber dados do usuário.

E o javascript é utilizado para que possamos controlar essas interações do usuário com o nosso HTML - e outras coisas, claro :)
Para esse controle, você deve utilizar a função `addEventListener` como explica a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

> `addEventListener()` registra uma única espera de evento em um único alvo.

Então o seu código deve ficar da seguinte forma:

```js
var test = [{
    name: "Rodrigo",
    rg: "00.000",
    tel: "(01) 00000-000"
  },
  {
    name: "Monica",
    rg: "85.000",
    tel: "(02) 00000-000"
  },
  {
    name: "Maria",
    rg: "68.000",
    tel: "(03) 00000-000"
  }
];

var options = '';
var inputMalt = document.getElementById('malt');

// Adicionar somente os options dinamicamente
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  options += '<option value="' + test[i].name + '" />';
}

// Adicionar a lista após popular toda a string options
document.getElementById('maltList').innerHTML = options;

// Adicionar o evento e obter e filtrar o dado selecionado
inputMalt.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var selectedOption = this.value;

  // Filtrando a lista para identificar o item selecionado
  var current = test.find(item => item.name === selectedOption);

  document.getElementById('rg').value = current.rg;
  document.getElementById('tel').value = current.tel;
});
```

```html
<input id="malt" name="malt" list="maltList" />
<datalist id="maltList"></datalist>
<input name="rg" type="text" id="rg"> //
<input name="tel" type="text" id="tel">
```

Comment: Perfeito irei me esforça e estudar cada vez mais para chega a esse nivel. obrigado era o exatamente o que eu queria.

Comment: @LeoVince, que legal que te ajudou! É isso ai :)